# Custom RoleProviderMembership ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, active-directory, ldap-query

First of all, thanks for reading my question. I hope you can help me. I have an application in asp.net with c# and I need to add security features. My client request that the authentication were against the active directory of the organization so I have an LDAP chain to do this... the other part of the problem is that my application uses specific roles on specific users so I can't use the groups of the ActiveDirectory.

I think I need to implement a double authentication: 
First the application authenticate that the user is valid via the LDAP query.
Then using the username of the LDAP query the application have to compare it against a table o Data Base that contain the users and it's roles.

With this information the application will give access to the modules that the user is allowed to.

I have research about this but I didn't find an implementation like this, only in separate ways.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You already know you need a custom RoleProvider. Have you written one? What issues are you having? You can get roles for a user however you want this way.

Comment: Thanks for your help. No I haven't written one yet on my own. I had tried the provider that have asp manager tools to create roles and users but I don't know how to combine it with the active directory authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use one of the standard RoleProviders, such as `SqlRoleProvider`, in conjunction with Windows Authentication.

[This blog post from Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/Recipe_3A00_-Implementing-Role_2D00_Based-Security-with-ASP.NET-2.0-using-Windows-Authentication-and-SQL-Server.aspx) gives a step-by-step recipe for doing this.

There's no need for a custom RoleProvider, unless you have other requirements that aren't met by the standard `SqlRoleProvider`.

Comment: Yes.. Indeed I have tried it and it work. The problem is that I'm not authenticating the user against the Active Directory and I find that this is not a correct form to supply security. But is a good option too. As I said it worked perfectly.